# Variable as a function at the same time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I really want to implement something like this.

```
myVar.myAnotherVar;
myVar.myMethod();
myVar("sample text");
```

and this is how jQuery implemented it

```
jQuery.fn;
jQuery.ajax();
jQuery("#myBtn");
```

How can I implement something like jQuery that  holds everything on a single namespace? is it something to do with prototype? how can a variable can be used to invoke as a function at the same time?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions in JavaScript are objects, you can arbitrarily add properties to them just like any other object:

```
function foo() {
    // Code for when you call `foo` goes here
}
foo.someData = "bar";
foo.someFunction = function() {
    // Code for when you call `foo.someFunction` goes here
};
```

What jQuery does is something slightly more complicated, and a bit unusual, in a couple of ways:

1. The `jQuery` function (usually aliased as `$`) is just a wrapper around a call to a constructor function that creates a new object. (The constructor function is called `init`.)
2. They've added a reference to that `init` function's `prototype` property in a property on the `jQuery` function called `fn`. Both properties (`jQuery.fn` and `init.prototype`) refer to an object that will become the instance's prototype when you use `new init`.
3. They've *also* referred to that same object from `jQuery.prototype`, even though `jQuery` isn't used as a constructor function. This is so that `$() instanceof $` will be `true`.

But you don't have to do those things just to do what you've described. You *can*, of course, but you don't have to.

If you want to do those two things, the basic structure looks like this:

```
var foo = function() {
    // The public function
    function foo(args, here) {
        return new init(args, here);
    }

    // The hidden constructor function
    function init(args, here) {
        // ...do something with `this`, perhaps
    }

    // The object that becomes the prototype of instances created via `new init`
    foo.fn = foo.prototype = init.prototype = {
        // An instance-specific function, like jQuery's `css`
        instanceMethod: function() {
            // Has access to `this`
        }
    };

    // A random piece of "static" (not instance-specific) data
    foo.someData = "bar";

    // A "static" (not instance-specific) function, like jQuery's `$.ajax`
    foo.staticMethod = function() {
        // Doesn't have (useful) access to `this`
    };

    return foo;
}();
```

Comment: @Mahan: The basics are, yeah.

Comment: @Mahan: I've added a more complex example of the kinds of things jQuery does above, hope that's useful.